# Exception: SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, azure-functions, mysql-5.7

I have a MySQL Server hosted on Azure with version: **5.7** with **Enforce SSL** connection set to **Enabled** and **Minimum TLS version**: **1.0**.

security setting:

[image: Security Settings of MySQL Server]

I have an **Azure function** that connects to that MySQL database and performs **CRUD** operations. So, For the last 12 months, It was working fine. But after an Azure update, Azure Function started using new JRE: zulu8.54.0.21-jre8.0.292-win_x64 instead of zulu8.52.0.23-jre8.0.282-win_x64 (on which it was working as expected).

Now, When the Azure function tries to connect to database, it has started throwing this exception:

> Exception: SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

I have used Java JPA to connect to the database and createEntityManagerFactory.

Please let me know how to resolve/overcome this exception.

Comment: have you tried this steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help the other community members.

We can connect Azure Database for MySQL to client applications using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
Below are the 4 steps to connect SSL to MySQL

- Obtain SSL Certificate
- Bind SSL
  Need to connect SSL to server using MySQL branch  below image is of sample example of SSL CA file
  [image]

Below is the Bash command for connecting server using MySQL

```
mysql.exe -h mydemoserver.mysql.database.azure.com -u Username@mydemoserver -p --ssl-mode=REQUIRED --ssl-ca=c:\ssl\BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem
```

- Enforcing SSL connections
- Verify the SSL connection

For further information check [SSL using MySQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl)